# Reading excel file with pandas and printing it for inserting it in http GET statement for Rest-API

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-requests, rest

I want to read each line of an excel file (.xlsx-file) in the column called 'ABC'. There are 4667 lines and each line there is a string.
I want to print each string. But it does not work.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


get_all_ABC = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\XXX\XXX2\XXX3\table.xlsx', header = 0)
row_iterator = get_all_ABC.iterrows()
_, last = row_iterator.__next__()`
for i, row in row_iterator:
   r= requests.get(row["ABC"])
   r= requests.get(last["ABC"])
   last = row
   data = (r.text)
   print ((r.text))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the requests library? That is for making HTTP requests. Also, it's almost always bad practice to iterate over rows in pandas, and 99% of the time unnecessary.

Also, `r.text` will be undefined as it's outside of the for loop scope.

Could you explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish? I don't think I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. The last few days I had to work on different projects. Yeah my bad. I slimmed down the original code. Ok, in the end I want to read out an excel file and insert that values in http requests methods, which are send to a RestAPI Server. The column 'ABC' of the excel file contains 4667 lines with sensor-numbers and these numbers have to be inserted as parameters in the http "GET-method". In the end I want to get the 4667 json-files from the RestAPI Server with all the values (data payload). Yeah, you're right with the r.text being out of scope. Was a typo. I edited it.

Comment: it was out of scope because apparently the tab key does not work while writing something on stackoverflow :(. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290026/markdown-editor-indent-and-outdent-functionality

Answer (score 0):

Julian L is right in his points. I mixed a lot up. I have to use the requests method for my overallproblem because I use the GET Method on a RESTApi Server and use the strings which are written in the round about 4000 lines in the column 'ABC' in the excel file. Before I tried the following python script (in that script I also do not use an iteration):

```
    import requests
    import pandas as pd 

    get_all_ABC = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\XXX\XXX2\XXX3\table.xlsx', skiprows=1).set_index('ABC')

    r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/api/sensors/data?ABC={get_all_ABC}')
    print(r.json())
```

But this does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

This thread leads nowhere. I delete this one and open a new one in which I describe the problem in more detail.